# Regular expression in javascript ignores newline

Tags: javascript, regex, newline, whitespace

I was wondering why the following regular expression results to TRUE:

```js
var users = "TEST\nTEST2";
var user  = "TEST5"
var position = users.search( user + "\n|$"); // result: 10
```

I want to search a `user` in `users`.
Can somebody please explain me the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex ends to `TEST5\n|$`, which means "either `TEST5\n` or the end of the string":

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/54118o7Nu7_uBDK0)

`TEST5\n` is not found, but the end of the string is, at index 10 (your string has 10 chars).

I guess you're looking for `user + "(\\n|$)"`:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ABTIL3SGqR_xmLZU)

Note that I escaped the backslash, since in a string literal. It won't change the result though, but it's the *regex-way* to write a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive lookahead

```
user + "(?=\\n|$)"
```

This means `user` which is followed by either `\n` or `$`